# How to increment each element in a list by 1 in LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, increment

I'm learning LISP and I am trying to write a function that adds 1 to each element inside my list. I first test for if the first element is a number or not then add 1 to the first element in the list. I then recursively call the function on the rest of the list but I get an error. Any help? Here's the function:

```
 (defun add-1-all (L)
    (cond (not (numberp (first L)) nil)
          (t (+1 (first L)) (add-1-all (rest L)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are more approaches:

1. When dealing with lists (see Joshua's comment), use  [`ENDP`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_endp.htm), [`FIRST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_firstc.htm) and [`REST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rest.htm), which are preferred over `NULL`, `CAR` and `CDR`. They convey the intent more clearly and in the case of `ENDP`, check that the argument is a proper-list. Imagine you pass a dotted-list built with `(cons 'a 'b)`, what should happen? `ENDP` detects that the list is not proper and signals an error.

   ```
   (defun add-1-all (list)
     (unless (endp list)
       (cons (1+ (first list))
             (add-1-all (rest list)))))
   ```

I used `UNLESS` for its `NIL` value, which some people might not like. You may want to explicitely return `NIL` when reaching the end of your list. In that case, stick with `COND` or just use `IF`.

2. Loop.

   ```
   (defun add-1-all (list)
     (loop for e in list collect (1+ e)))
   ```
3. Make it work on arrays too, not just lists.

   ```
   (defun add-1-all (sequence)
     (map (type-of sequence) #'1+ sequence))
   ```

Comment: <3 For the map type-of idiom, nifty!

Comment: Why the check? If I pass a number I get `The value of SEQUENCE should be of type SEQUENCE` while without it I get `There are no sequences of type XXX`.

Comment: **"Use ENDP, FIRST and REST, which are preferred over NULL, CAR and CDR."**  Just to clarify for OP (and some of the rest of the answer points to this), these functions are preferred when dealing with cons cells *as lists*.  If you're working with an arbitrary tree tree structure, or testing for NIL in other contexts, NULL, CAR, and CDR are probably the way to go.  The difference between CAR/CDR and FIRST/REST is just stylistic for lists, but ENDP/NULL actually have different behavior on non-lists. ENDP on non-lists is an error, whereas NULL on non-lists is just false.

Comment: @Sylwester You are perfectly right, I was just being overzealous. Removed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish your goal would be to use map. Map applies a function to each element of a sequence. That way one does not have to take care of details like iterating through the sequence. In the code below I use mapcar which works only on lists.

```
(defun add-1 (list)
  (mapcar #'1+ list))
```

To find out about other mapping functions that CL provides run (apropos "map") and use (describe ) to find out more. Or better yet use the [clhs search engine](http://xach.com/clhs) or the [extended CL documentation search engine](http://l1sp.org/html/)

The solution you provided is attempting to solve the problem through recursion. The general idea is to traverse the list using first/rest while building a new one with the elements incremented by one. When the list reaches the end (You can use the functions null or endp to test that the end of the list has been reached) the new list should be returned. One of the problems with your solution is that it lacks an accumulator. Also your base-case (the condition that signals to stop the recursion) is wrong.

A couple of other pointers. Use an editor that formats your code as it is difficult to read. Also CL is not a Lisp-1 so you can use list as a variable name and it won't collide with the function list. They have separate namespaces.  It is also helpful to post the error message and the explain what/how your solution is trying to do. You may also find [this textbook](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) useful for learning Lisp

Answer (score 1):

You could write  (+ 1 (first L))     or  (1+ (first L))    but you didn't write that.

Also, you should use cons to tack the result on the first element to the result of the rest of them.
Also, did you really want to drop off all the elements after the first non-number?  Or did you want to assume all elements were numbers, in which case you should learn about map or mapcar, which allows you to solve the problem in 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is wrong if you compile it you get several errors and warnings, is important a good lisp syntax and also knowing what you are writing. If you are learning lisp I reccomend you to get a confortable environment for that like [slime and quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/)

```
; SLIME 2015-06-01; compiling (DEFUN ADD-1-ALL ...)

; file: /tmp/file451NPJ
; in: DEFUN ADD-1-ALL
;     (1 (FIRST L))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call

;     (REST L)
; --> CDR 
; ==>
;   L
; 
; note: deleting unreachable code

;     (COND (NOT (NUMBERP (FIRST L)) NIL) (T (1 (FIRST L)) (ADD-1-ALL (REST L))))
; ==>
;   (IF NOT
;       (PROGN (NUMBERP (FIRST L)) NIL)
;       (COND (T (1 (FIRST L)) (ADD-1-ALL (REST L)))))
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: NOT
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     NOT
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
;   printed 1 note
```

Then it is a good idea to use recursion for doing this task, for recursions is important to know when to stop and the base case of your algorithm

In you case you can also use if for this two path the function will be this:

```
(defun add-1-all (list)
  (cond
    ((null list) nil)
    (t (cons (1+ (car list))(add-1-all (cdr list))))))
```

I recommend you to try doing this using a tail recursive function for better perfomance and a great learning.

Also with lisp you can use more functional style, when time comes you will learn this, like using higher order functions in this case your function is as follows:

```
;; functional programming higher order functions
(defun add-1-all-ho (list)
  (mapcar #'1+ list))
```